# Playing waveform with NAudio lower for each turn

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to play a byte buffer with NAudio. I created a winforms application for the task.

[image]

But when I play the sound (created with Math.sin) subsequently, the volume goes lower and lower for every playback. Why?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace beeper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        const int sampling_freq = 44100;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            double freq = 1000;
            var seconds = 0.5;
            
            var length = (int)(seconds * sampling_freq);
            bytes = new byte[length];

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                var offset = 80 * Math.Sin(i * freq / sampling_freq * Math.PI * 2);

                bytes[i] = (byte)(128 + offset);
            }
        }

        private void btnBeep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var format = new WaveFormat(sampling_freq, 8, 1);
            var provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(format);
            provider.AddSamples(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            var wo = new WaveOut();
            wo.Init(provider);
            wo.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

## Recording in audacity

[image]

Not wonder it sounds like it does when looking at this waveform thats both offsetted and distorted in some strange way. I search for a pattern, but I cannot really find one.

https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/729

Comment: Is it possible your problem is you are creating a new `wo` but not `using` to make sure the old `wo` is properly disposed of? Note that you can't dispose of `wo` until enough time has passed to finish the sound...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding a whole new playback channel each time you click the play button. If you don't close those channels then they will just continue to play silence, so you end up with multiple silent channels mixed with one active sound, giving you the result you're seeing. The more times you push the button the quieter the output will be.

Either you need to close your channels after the tone completes (using a timer or similar) or create one channel and reuse it:

```
    private BufferedWaveProvider provider;
    private WaveOut waveOut;
    
    private void btnBeep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveOut == null)
        {
            var format = new WaveFormat(sampling_freq, 8, 1);
            provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(format);
            waveOut = new WaveOut();
            waveOut.Init(provider);
            waveOut.Play();
        }
        
        provider.ClearBuffer();
        provider.AddSamples(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

Calling `ClearBuffer` removes any remaining buffered samples so hitting the button repeatedly doesn't just queue up a whole stack of output. If you want to play multiple overlapping tones you'll need to do multiple channels or handle mixing yourself.

If you do want overlaps I suggest you check out [`MixingWaveProvider32`](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveProviders/MixingWaveProvider32.cs). As it stands it's a bit constrained, but you should be able to either use it as is (with the appropriate conversion sample provider).

Comment: So `waveOut.Play()` will continue playing after the `provider` runs out of samples?

Comment: @NetMage `WaveOut` will pause when the provider runs out of data. But `BufferedWaveProvider` with default settings will produce data infinitely. If you set `ReadFully` to false it stops when the buffered data runs out.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `button1_Click` event to properly `Dispose` of the `WaveOut` with `using` and wait until the sound finishes seems to work fine. Otherwise I think you would need to use one global `WaveOut`.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    double freq = 1000;

    var length = (int)(seconds * sampling_freq);
    bytes = new byte[length];

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var offset = 80 * Math.Sin(i * freq / sampling_freq * Math.PI * 2);

        bytes[i] = (byte)(128 + offset);
    }
}

private void btnBeep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var format = new WaveFormat(sampling_freq, 8, 1);
    var provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(format);
    provider.AddSamples(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    using var wo = new WaveOut();
    wo.Init(provider);
    wo.Play();
    Thread.Sleep((int)Math.Ceiling(1000*seconds) + 100);
}
```

Comment: It works, but it blocks the UI thread. And it's still creating a new `WaveOut` every time you click, which seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @Corey Is there better documentation on things like `WaveOut` for NAudio?

Comment: Documentation is spotty. I generally just go to the source when I hit something I'm not sure of. It's one of the things I like about open-source code :)